# Cordova plugin dialog confirm does not send the response to the function called in android but it does on web

Tags: android, cordova, browser, dialog, popup

When I use this code:

```
function dialogConfirm() {
    var message = "Am I Confirm Dialog?";
    var title = "CONFIRM";
    var buttonLabels = "YES,NO";
    navigator.notification.confirm(message, confirmCallback, title, buttonLabels);

function confirmCallback(buttonIndex) {
    navigator.notification.alert("You clicked " + buttonIndex + " button!",null,"helo","Nic");
}

 }
```

However on android when I deploy with Cordova and I click on one of the btns of confirm the alert does not popUp so I tried with some text and I found out that the function confirmCallBack is never called whatever btn I click so does anyone know what can I do to call the confirmCallBack function or is it just a bug with the plugin in android. I remind you that on Windows Browser it works perfectly so the issue is either with the library or with my device it is a Moto G 3rd Generation android 7.0.1 Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried the **confirm* without **title, buttonLabels**
navigator.notification.confirm('Delete?', function() {
       alert("Hi");
    });

Comment: works just fine for me on android devices. Maybe you can try to update the notification plugin?

Comment: @NullPointer yes the call works perfectly the issue is that on my phone it does not start the function when I click "Yes" e.x

Comment: @QuickFix I will give it a try

Comment: Did not work! Anything new?

Comment: ok forget about Cordova plugin and just try to put javascript confirm with callback and check if it is working?

Comment: ok tell me one thing I hope you have written this code in *deviceready* event when using in android with cordova?

Answer (score 2):

Your options buttons are a **string** instead of an **array**.

> **message**: Dialog message. (String)
>
> **confirmCallback**: Callback to invoke with index of button pressed (1,
> 2, or 3) or when the dialog is dismissed without a button press (0).
> (Function)
>
> **title**: Dialog title. (String) (Optional, defaults to Confirm)
>
> **buttonLabels**: Array of strings specifying button labels. (Array)
> (Optional, defaults to [OK,Cancel])

Try this sample from the original [Dialogs plugin documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/#navigatornotificationconfirm):

```
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
    console.log('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
    navigator.notification.alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
}

navigator.notification.confirm(
    'You are the winner!', // message
     onConfirm,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Game Over',           // title
    ['Restart','Exit']     // buttonLabels
);
```